# YouTube API get video url is missing url_encoded_fmt_stream_map and undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native, youtube-api

Restful Info

```
url: https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=${videoId}&el=embedded&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en
method: 'GET',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
```

Replaced: ${videoId} = ABEVNHqmbJ4 or YzXi5HpgYGc

I didn't found any stream data on key **url_encoded_fmt_stream_map**

Answer (score 0):

url_encoded_fmt_stream_map seems to disappear from more and more videos, I think they are removing it from the videos meta data...

Comment: It seems to be so, my solution to use other 3rd party API to get video URL: https://english.api.rakuten.net/Top-Rated/api/get-video-and-audio-url. It's work okay, except it's not fast enough as expected.